# Android Geocoder Timeout error

Tags: android, google-geocoder, userlocation

> UPDATE: Looks Like it is because of google map service is down for the past day
>   [See here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9153)

Im using geocoder to get user address from his lat, long. Till yesterday all was good , but today its giving me a timeout error:

> Unable connect to Geocoder
>                                                                      java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server
>                                                                          at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
>                                                                          at LocationAddress$1.run(LocationAddress.java:32)

I read at many places GeoCoder has this issue, and alternative is to use web api to get the address.
Rather than doing this is there any other solution

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            String result = null;
            UserLocation u = null;
            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude, longitude, 1);
```

Permissions:
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

This is what im doing with lat long.

Any fix ???????????? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: you added internet permission?

Comment: @Fabian i said it was working earlier.. and yes i hv added all the permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Google Geocoder is down

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9153

Comment: Thaanks fr the issue update. im using the web api to get location address based on lat and long for nw